# A file with actual size 1 byte uses 8 blocks of 4096 bytes on the filesystem

Tags: linux, wsl-2, filesize, diskspace, block-device

In my home directory, I created a file named `file_size_test.txt`.
I added a single character `a` to its content (no newline).
Actual file size of `file_size_test.txt` = 1 byte.

However, `stat file_size_test.txt` shows that the file occupies 8 blocks.
Block size = 4096 bytes.

NB: I'm running WSL with Ubuntu.

Details here:
[image]

I was expecting that the file `file_size_test.txt` would only use 1 block.

A similar question was already asked here but the only answer provided didn't help me (at least as it was expressed):
[Linux block size issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769534/linux-block-size-issue)

Comment: Nothing to do with programming - try [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two notions of `block size` :

```
$ sudo blockdev --getbsz /dev/sdc
4096
$ sudo blockdev --getpbsz /dev/sdc
512
```

The `Blocks: 8` in `stat` is in terms of physical block size `8*512=4096`.